# excel - from 2 columns of group and subgroup - to make a column to each group and below the subgroups

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to make from two columns of group (repeating) and subgroup -> column to each group (as header) and below its subgroup. Exactly as described in the picture.[explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8gvC.png)

Comment: It is great to hear what you want.  Now please show us what you have tried by editing the question above and adding any code or formulas and tell us exactly what is going wrong and where.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: create a pivot table and drag the first column into the "column" list - http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps:

1. copy column A to column E

2. use remove duplicates in column E alone

3. copy and transpose column E to F1:Z1 (depands of the amount of groups)

4. used the following formula in cell F2, and then copied and paste as needed

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(F$1,$A:$A,0)&":B"&COUNTIFS($A:$A,F$1)+MATCH(F$1,$A:$A,0)-1),ROW(1:1),2),"")
```

Any better way ? I want eventually to enter each group as title to the name manager and use the subgroups as it values.